# When does postincrement i++ get executed?

Tags: c++, post-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

In C++ on a machine code level, when does the postincrement++ operator get executed?

The [precedence table](http://cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence) indicates that postfix++ operators are level 2:  which means in

```
int x = 0 ;
int y = x++ + x++ ;  // ans: y=0
```

The postfix ++'s execute *first*.

However, it would seem that the logical operation of this line is the addition happens first (0+0), but how does that happen?

What I imagine, is the following:

```
// Option 1:
// Perform x++ 2 times.
// Each time you do x++, you change the value of x..
// but you "return" the old value of x there?
int y = 0 + x++ ;  // x becomes 1, 0 is "returned" from x++

// do it for the second one..
int y = 0 + 0 ;  // x becomes 2, 0 is "returned" from x++... but how?
// if this is really what happens, the x was already 1 right now.
```

So, the other option is although x++ is higher on the precedence table that x + x, the code generated due to x++ is inserted *below* the addition operation

```
// Option 2:  turn this into
int y = x + x ; // 
x++ ;
x++ ;
```

That second option seems to make more sense, but I'm interested in the order of operations here. Specifically, *when does x change*?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points. This is undefined behavior (not just undefined order, *anything* is permitted to happen).

Comment: Operator precedence tells you nothing about order of evaluation.

Comment: The answer is the same, but the question is different.

Comment: I have voted to reopen. The question is not about the UB of the expression, but rather about the semantics of `x++`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of jumping on the details of the example that is UB, I will discuss the following example that is perfectly fine:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
int c = a++ + b++;
```

Now, the precedence of operators means that the last line is equivalent to:

```
int c = (a++) + (b++);
```

And not:

```
int c = (a++ + b)++; // compile time error, post increment an rvalue
```

On the other hand, the semantics of the post increment are equivalent to two separate instructions (from here on is just a mental picture):

```
a++; // similar to: (__tmp = a, ++a, __tmp) 
     // -- ignoring the added sequence points of , here
```

That is, the original expression will be interpreted by the compiler as:

```
auto __tmp1 = a;         // 1
auto __tmp2 = b;         // 2
++a;                     // 3
++b;                     // 4
int c = __tmp1 + __tmp2; // 5
```

But the compiler is allowed to reorder the 5 instructions as long as the following constraints are met (where `x>y` means `x` must be executed before `y`, or `x` precedes `y`):

```
1 > 3        // cannot increment a before getting the old value
2 > 4        // cannot increment b before getting the old value
1 > 5, 2 > 5 // the sum cannot happen before both temporaries are created
```

There are no other constraints in the order of execution of the different instructions, so the following are all valid sequences:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 5, 3, 4
1, 3, 2, 4, 5
...
```

Comment: This is a very good answer and addresses the question directly.  Ty.

Comment: In the example here and OP question you don't / can't get a real surprise though by those order variations. Mentioning examples with undefined / surprise results can tell the  relevance of the explanation: e.g.  `int i = 0; i = (i++) + (i++);`  on gcc (v9) yields `1` in the end. Another compiler, MSVC, yields `2`...

Answer (score 7):

This

```
int y = x++ + x++ ;
```

[is undefined behavior. Anything can happen,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/57428) including some unreasonable results, program crashing or whatever else. Just don't do that.

Comment: That code does't do what you make think it does, but ... program crashing ? I wouldn't say that.

Comment: @cprogrammer: The point is, it's undefined behavior. Crashing may not be likely, but it would be allowed.

Comment: @cprogrammer, @Fred Larson: The key idea here is that you should not waste time thinking of what might happen - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4265736/57428 - you should just not write code like that.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ there are things called "[sequence points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azk8zbxd.aspx)".  If you alter a value more than once without an intervening sequence point, the behaviour is **undefined**.

Consider the following:

```
int x = 0;
int y = x++ + x++;
```

The value of y could be 0, 1 or some other completely random value.

Bottom line is, don't do it.  Nothing good can come of it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, is seems like the following happens

When you use `x++`, `x` increments after the operation is complete.

```
int y = x++ + x++ ;
// First add 0+0
// Increment x
// Increment
```

While

```
int y = ++x + ++x ;
// Add (increment x) and (increment x) = 1+1 = 2
```

However, different compilers will handle it differently and your application might crash if you increment twice in the same statement.