# Calculate sum with ++ and order of calculation

Tags: c#

I have this code snippet below. Is it correct to describe that sum will be `0` because `sum++` will be ignored as assignment of `sum +=` will be adding 0 before increasing the value? Or how is this best described? I mean if I use `sum += sum  + 1` the result is different.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   sum += sum++;
}

// Sum has end value 0
```

Comment: So what's the question here? You answered and proved your own question...

Comment: Order of Operations. And what might happen if you switch to sum += ++sum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does postincrement i++ get executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433852/when-does-postincrement-i-get-executed)

Comment: I think the question is how; sum += sum++; is different from sum += sum + 1;

Comment: I think you are correct, yes. Essentially it loads `sum` into memory position 1 . Then it loads sum again into memory position 2. It then adds one to memory position 2 and stores the result to `sum` (without updating memory position 2). It then adds up memory positions 1 and 2 (both still 0) and assigns the result of that to sum so sum is 0 again.

Comment: What about `sum += ++sum;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum++` increments the value, but it returns the value it was *before* it was incremented. `++sum` increments the value as well, but returns the value *after* the incrementing.

You can think `sum++` as returning the value, then increasing the value (even though that's not what's happening)

And you think `++sum` as increasing the value and then returning it.

So, `sum += ++sum` *is* the same as `sum += sum + 1`, as far as final result goes.

In your example, `sum++` returns zero, `sum` is set two `1`, but then you set it back to `0` and it repeats.